# Django 2.1: is it possible to include Ngrok's Domain in an email instead of localhost's?

Tags: python, django, email

i am using **Ngrok** to run my website with **https://**, and when i send an activation email to myself, instead of seeing **'https://something.ngrok.io/...'** i get **'http://localhost:8000/...'.**

This is the code responsible for sending the Activation Email which - to my opinion - it should send Ngrok's domain not the development domain ...

```
...
current_site = get_current_site(request)
mail_subject = 'Activate your customer account.'
message = render_to_string('user_register_email/account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            'token': user_token.make_token(user),
        })
receiver = form.cleaned_data['email']
email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[receiver]
        )
email.send()
messages.info(
            request, f'An activation link has been sent to %s' % (receiver))
return redirect('accounts:login')
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_site.domain` returns the value set on the site instance, you can either change it from the admin panel, or you can use `request.get_host()` instead